# jQuery Hide / Show (div with modified id attr)

Tags: jquery, hide, show, show-hide

I'm having truoble doing this:

```
<div id="show-menu">Show Menu</div>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#show-menu').click(function() {
                $(this).animate({marginRight:'70px'}, 500);
                $('#menu').animate({width:'300px'}, 500);
                $('.menu-menu-principal-container, #header h1').animate({marginRight:'70px'}, 500);
                $(".menu-menu-principal-container, #header h1").show("slow");
                $("#show-menu").hide("slow");
                $("#hide-menu").show("slow");
                $(this).text('Hide Menu');
                $(this).attr('id', 'hide-menu');            
            });
            $('#hide-menu').click(function() {
                $(this).animate({marginRight:'-70px'}, 500);
                $('#menu').animate({width:'100px'}, 500);
                $('.menu-menu-principal-container, #header h1').animate({marginRight:'-70px'}, 500);
                $(".menu-menu-principal-container, #header h1").hide("slow");
                $(this).text('Show Menu');
                $(this).attr('id', 'show-menu');
            });
        })

    </script>
```

If I click on Show Menu (#show-menu) it shows correctly, but when I click again in the Hide Menu (#hide-menu) it wont hide? It does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use jQuery [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Preferably I would use delegate like this

```
$('body').delegate('#show-menu', 'click', function() { ... your code ... });
$('body').delegate('#hide-menu', 'click', function() { ... your code ... });
```

Remember you can delegate from a different position in the DOM instead of `$('body').delegate();` you could use `$('#myparentContainer').delegate();`

The alternative would be to use live events like this

```
$('#show-menu').live('click', function() { ... your code ...});
$('#hide-menu').live('click', function() { ... your code ...});
```

Answer (score 1):

hide-menu does not exist during the document ready function call, and hence will not be bounded.
you would need to use live to have the event bounded as it appears.

Answer (score 0):

What .click() does is to bind a function to the click event to the selector. Since you're doing $('#hide-menu').click(function() before a #hide-menu html element exist, it won't work, you should place the $('#hide-menu').click(function() { after  $(this).attr('id', 'hide-menu');

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#show-menu').click(function() {
                $(this).animate({marginRight:'70px'}, 500);
                $('#menu').animate({width:'300px'}, 500);
                $('.menu-menu-principal-container, #header h1').animate({marginRight:'70px'}, 500);
                $(".menu-menu-principal-container, #header h1").show("slow");
                $("#show-menu").hide("slow");
                $("#hide-menu").show("slow");
                $(this).text('Hide Menu');
                $(this).attr('id', 'hide-menu');  
$('#hide-menu').click(function() {
                $(this).animate({marginRight:'-70px'}, 500);
                $('#menu').animate({width:'100px'}, 500);
                $('.menu-menu-principal-container, #header h1').animate({marginRight:'-70px'}, 500);
                $(".menu-menu-principal-container, #header h1").hide("slow");
                $(this).text('Show Menu');
                $(this).attr('id', 'show-menu');
            });          
            });

        })
```

you can also use live() since it "binds now or in the future" but that's less efficient, since you "know" when the #hide-menu attribute appear in the DOM, you should bind the event there